# How do I use the hot air balloon by Hyrule Field Chasm?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I found a hot air balloon next to a big hole called Hyrule Field Chasm. It's tied to the ground with 3 chains. I've tried lighting the burner with a fire arrow, attacking the chains with an axe, and grabbing the balloon with Ultrahand, but it all had no effect.

How do I use the hot air balloon?

[image: Hot air balloon]

Comment: The hot air balloon is now gone. I believe a researcher used it to enter the depths. after I accepted the quest "Camera Work in the Depths".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a hot air balloon is chained down, it generally means that **the balloon belongs to someone else**, and you can't steal it (or at least, you're not supposed to be able to steal it). In this case, I think it either belongs to Robbie or the survey team.

If you want your own hot air balloon, you can buy one at a few dispensers in the world (for example, the one in Kakariko), as well as find them lying around in various places (particularly throughout the Depths).